# nested MVC views and partial views sitefinity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the view below which has a partial loaded onto it. Now I would like to update the partial but not reload the actual view. I am using MVC in sitefinity so do not have the use of master pages.

```
<div class="pr-nav">
    <div class="btn btn-primary">
        User Guide
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary">
        Key Info
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

@Html.Partial("subListPartial")
</div>
```

Comment: How would you like to update the partial? On a button click?

Answer (score 0):

You could do an ajax request and return a partial view as an action result in your controller and replace the partial.

Here is a example of an action with a partial result:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public PartialViewResult User(EditUser model)
    {
        return PartialView("_EditAccountForm", model);
    }
```